# Problem Printing Indices with Splitidx Package

Tags: indexing, splitidx

Following the instructions in the [Splitidx Documentation](http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/splitindex/splitidx.pdf), I've been trying to add indices to a `book` document. It compiles witout error. However, none of the indices print. Here's an example of the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek.polutoniko,english]{babel}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage[makeindex]{splitidx}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\newindex[Index Locorum]{loc}
\newindex[Index Nomimun]{nom}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\title{Title Here} 
\author{Author Here}
\maketitle{}

\chapter{First Chapter}
Here's some text with a \sindex[nom]{Name}Name and \sindex[loc]{Location}Location.

\backmatter

\printindex*

\end{document}
```

I've also tried the other printing style indicated in the documentation, but that doesn't print the indices either:

```
\printindex[loc][Index Locorum]
\printindex[nom][Index Nominum]
```

The `sindex` entries **do** show up in the `idx` file:

```
\indexentry[nom]{Name|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry[loc]{Location|hyperpage}{1}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Here's my LaTeX version: `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian)`. I'm running this on Linux Mint 18.2, and compiling with Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Did you run `splitindex`?

Comment: Hot damn! Running that and then compiling again **did** print the index. It's still not (even after multiple iterations) showing up in the table of contents though.

Comment: `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}` should be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do a few things:

1. entries for the index *must* be after `\frontmatter` (or something has to be done with `\roman` because of the usage of `greek`);
2. you have to run `splitindex` to actually *make* the indices
3. add `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}` in order that the indices are added to the table of contents.

Example

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek.polutoniko,english]{babel}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage[makeindex]{splitidx}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\newindex[Index Locorum]{loc}
\newindex[Index Nomimun]{nom}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\title{Title Here} 
\author{Author Here}
\maketitle{}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{First Chapter}
Here's some text with a \sindex[nom]{Name}Name and \sindex[loc]{Location}Location.

\backmatter

\printindex*

\end{document}
```

[image]